# drupal commerce kickstart admin access denied

Tags: drupal, admin, commerce

I am new to drupal and I have completed the installation process for commerce kickstart in my Ubuntu system. The thing is that when I am trying to access the admin page i get an error "403 access denied". I am using the predefined Username and password which is admin admin. I am using PHP 5.3.6. Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you are logged in as master admin (user id 1) you should be able to access everything. So, if you are trying to access admin page with that account something is wrong with your installation then, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be a bit more clear, after the installation you will need to log in to the system. The login page is available at yoursiteurl/user or if you don't have the Clean URLs turned on, it will be on yoursiteurl/?q=user/login

If you don't have Clean URLs turned on, also admin pages will have to be accessed differently, ie. yoursiteurl/?q=admin

More about turning on [Clean URLs in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/256410)